# Export more than 1000 rows in Powershell

Tags: powershell, export-csv

I am trying to access some data about Unified Groups using PowerShell.

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | ? {$_.AccessType -eq "Public"}
```

This is the command I am using, however I am also trying to export this data to CSV.
So the command becomes

```
Get-UnifiedGroup | ? {$_.AccessType -eq "Public"} | Export-Csv c:\temp\azureadusers.csv
```

But it only displays first 1000 results in the csv file and I am trying to get all of the data. I am new to PowerShell so I am still learning this.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: [`-ResultSize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps#-resultsize): *The ResultSize parameter specifies the maximum number of results to return. If you want to return all requests that match the query, use unlimited for the value of this parameter. The default value is `1000`.*

Answer (score 0):

you may want too look at the [-Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps#-filter) Parameter too. It's always a good thing to filter as far left as possible. Mostly because it's free Performance gain.

```
-Filter {AccessType -eq "Public"}
```